# Using from base in derived class C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, using, radix

From this code snippet from "The C++ Programming Language 4th edition" (page 1215), I don't understand the use of "using"; the methods are not being overridden by the derived class; why not just use these 2 methods from normal inheritance from thread?

```
struct guarded_thread : thread {
    using thread::thread;
    using thread::operator=;
    ~guarded_thread() { if (joinable()) join(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the constructors with parameters from the class you derive from without explicitly telling that you want to do so!

If you NOT want to use the `using` of the constructor, you have to write all variants of the constructor for your own class and forward all parameters manual to the constructor of of the class you derive from. Lots of work for nothing! So simply tell the compiler, that we want use the constructor of the class we derive from. Ready to use!

As `operator=` is also a special function, which the compiler generates on its own as long we do not provide some, we also must tell the compiler that we want simply to use the ones from the class we derive from.